# Правильно ли построено предложение во времени?

Tags: времена

У группы Radio Tapok есть песня Атака мертвецов и там такая строка:

Их всех рвёт, знав исход, они шли вперёд!

Друг говорит, что предложение построено неправильно, нарушено время.

Их всех рвет - настоящее время
знав исход, они шли вперед - получается прошедшее время

Допускается ли в литературных произведения, таких как в данном случае "песня" или "стихотворение" подобные допущения, допустим как "автор так видит" и тд.

Comment: Нету слова "знав".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Почему нет? Деепричастие прошедшего времени.

Comment: Не слышал раньше такого. Поверю)

Comment: Здесь же нарушены все условия: никогда не **знав** раньше блатной среды, человек не ждал этого боя... [А. И. Солженицын. Архипелаг ГУЛаг (1958-1973)]

Comment: @ Александр Стрелец  Расскажите пжста о деепричастии совершенного вида "знав".  Как мне кажется, оно не укладывается в обычную грамматику, да и семантику тоже.  Разве нельзя сказать "зная исход, они шли вперёд".  Знали и шли – одновременное действие. Но люди за вас активно проголосовали.  Вероятно, я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: @Sharon Слово "знав" есть? Есть. Это был ответ на комментарий Артёма. Вот и всё. // "Знав" – деепр. **несоверш.** вида (как и "зная"), "знавши" – его разг. форма. // "Активно проголосовали" – преувеличение. // Я бы тоже сказал "зная исход, они шли вперёд", но тогда в стихотворной строчке добавляется один слог. Видимо, из-за размера и ритма автор выбрал форму прошедш. времени. // Есть причастие "знавший", почему бы и "знав" не быть, тем более что во многих предложениях "зная" не будет подходить.

Comment: @ Александр Стрелец  Спасибо за ответ. В Нацкорпусе "знав" редко встречается (старые или диалектные/просторечные тексты). А грамматика у деепричастий НСВ особая, вся расписанная, с причастиями их нельзя сравнивать. Этот суффикс только для причастий СВ используется. Со всех сторон эта форма неправильная. Размер?  Можно незаметно втиснуть, это же песня.  А Солженицын почему его использует? Может, в нем особый смысл какой есть? Извините за расспросы,  просто хочу понять. Мне же категорически хочется изгнать это слово  из языка :))

Comment: @Sharon Вы же вроде бы всегда топите за разнообразие языка и против "одной гребёнки" :)  В нашем же случае, как мне кажется, "знав" не может пока исчезнуть. Пролистав все примеры Нацкорпуса (да, в основном старые), я не почувствовал его устаревшим, особенно с глаголами СВ. А вот в отрицании и с "никогда" его вообще нельзя заменить, например: "Никогда их не знав, он сделался..." Ну а уж в стихах и подавно:  "Не знав коварную измену, тебе я душу отдавал..."

Comment: @ Александр Стрелец Ну да, поэты так пишут (или писали): Чуть отрок, Ольгою плененный, Сердечных мук еще не знав...   Можно сказать: никогда прежде  не зная. Есть форма: не знавши. А в карте слов даже примеров с этим словом нет.  Некоторые формы устаревают, но потом используются в других стилях. А это "знав" только если в пародиях можно использовать. Хотела написать вам пародию, но поэтического таланта не хватает, увы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***«Их всех рвёт, знав исход, они шли вперёд!».***

1. Это же песня, особая художественная форма изображения действительности в авторском стиле.

Она как бы состоит **из фрагментов** (образов, мыслей, картин, взятых из настоящего или прошлого). Запятая же разделяет эти фрагменты.

Не стоит, наверное, искать там связанный текст и соответствие времен в обычном понимании.

2. **Примечание**

Вызывает сомнение форма **"знав"**. Вообще говоря, деепричастия бывают несовершенного и совершенного вида.

От глагола несовершенного вида "знать" можно образовать деепричастия несовершенного вида "**зная**" (нейтр.) и "**знавши**" (разг.). Деепричастия несовершенного вида обозначают действие, протекающее **одновременно** с основным действием. Форма "знав" выглядит устаревшей или диалектной, но в любом случае она не нормируется в современной речи в качестве нейтральной.

Возможный вариант: ***зная исход, они шли вперёд***.